# build grid dynamically

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a vertical grid. Each row of the grid has an image, progress bar and some text in it. The number of rows in the grid is dynamic (from database data) and so I assume I have to create this in cpde?

Since I'm a complete Android beginner I wonder how I best tackle this.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you start by reading app the documenation on GridLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).  You can create some view representing your grid cell, then create the grid and dynamically add instances of your view class to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Android GridView Widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). It works in the same way as a ListView.